# installing android tools adb - keep getting error

Tags: virtualbox, adb, android-sdk

I searched the stack and even googled for an answer before posting here.
I am new to linux (installed it only yesterday) 
I am running it from a virtualBox, it is the Santoku linux (which as far as I understand is based on lbuntu, so I hope this is the right place to post my question)

after updating the android sdk manager every time the machine was booting in I got an error staying that something is wrong with the android-tools-adb & android-tools-fastboot. 
I thought I probably was due to corrupt installation so I tried to reinstall the packages but I kept getting an error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/android-tools-adb_4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu23_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/android-tools-fastboot_4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu23_amd64.deb
```

so I decided to removed, purged and cleaned these packages. Tried again to reinstall using:

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

to get just the adb tools, got the same error as above.

Here is what the I see in the terminal

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0
  gir1.2-xkl-1.0 libtimezonemap1 python3-cairo python3-gi-cairo
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  android-tools-adb
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/65.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 230 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 254338 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../android-tools-adb_4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu23_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking android-tools-adb (4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu23) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/android-tools-adb_4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu23_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/adb', which is also in package android-sdk 23.0.2-ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/android-tools-adb_4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu23_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Am I doing it all right? Or did I mess it up somewhere, or am I using the wrong command?

P.S.
The android sdk manager doesn't work as well and it returns this error:

`Invalid desktop entry file: '/usr/share/applications/santoku-androidsdk.desktop'`

Thank you

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy android-tools-adb android-sdk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There only can be one.

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/android-tools-adb_4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu23_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/adb', which is also in package android-sdk 23.0.2-ubuntu1
```

First you have to remove the package `android-sdk`

```
sudo apt-get remove android-sdk
```

to install `android-tools-adb`.

After that execute

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

to repair your package system.

Comment: Thanks A.B. That worked. so I removed the sdk then installed adb and fastboot. I got the same error when I was trying to install the sdk after the adb install.  I decided to remove the vm and reinstall al from the start. Maybe I messed something there.